# Are there reasons why using a ViewModel feature object is not good practice?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I am building a modern Android app (Kotlin, Compose, Coroutines, etc.) using a single activity with many "features" (dozens).  Rather than have a very large, single, concrete ViewModel class, I am inclined to have a per-feature, short and sweet, ViewModel object singleton:

`object FooViewModel : ViewModel() {...}`

I have seen on the order of a half dozen public sample apps that use view model classes. None use a view model singleton object.

I have been using multiple, per-feature, singleton view model objects now for about six months in my app. So far, there does not seem to be any issues but I am suspicious that there may be problems lurking in this approach.

Singletons have been frowned upon in the literature in the past few years (maybe longer) but the issues mostly involve the underlying implementation (threading, visibility, performance). Kotlin has solved all theses issues by using the "object" keyword to achieve a safe, efficient implementation.

It might be the case that not using singleton objects for view models is just the fashion. Then again, there might be a valid reason why developers do not use a singleton view model class.

Surfacing that reason, if it exists, is the point of my question.

Comment: that a look at this, it is a good sample app from google. https://github.com/android/nowinandroid

Comment: @Lino you are correct in that NowInAndroid is a good sample app. As are others I have looked at. All of them use concrete view model classes, not a singleton object.  I will try to edit my question to clarify it. Thanks.